# Error trying to login a hardcoded account

Tags: c#, authentication, webforms

I have two textbox to type usename and password. One button to login. Login will pass if username and password is correct, but i have error at the part when username and password is wrong. I got

> Error 1   Syntax error, '(' expected

and

> Error 2   ) expected

Below are the codes in the login button.

```
if (txtUser.Text == "jon" && txtPass.Text == "any")
{
    Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
}
if else (txtUser.Text == "" && txtPass.Text == "")
{
    lblError.Text = "Invalid user or pass";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the `if else` - that'll give you a syntax error.

```
if (txtUser.Text == "jon" && txtPass.Text == "any")
{
    Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
}
else if (txtUser.Text == "" && txtPass.Text == "")
{
    lblError.Text = "Invalid user or pass";
}
```

For the purpose of your test you can probably just remove this part:

```
if (txtUser.Text == "" && txtPass.Text == "")
```